# Implementing a database of a product attribute

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I want to design an online store.

This store has a few menus:

## table: menu

```
id  |   name
1       TV
2       computer
```

and each menu has some products:

## table: product

```
id  |   menu_id    |   title   |   body
1       1              t1          b1
2       2              t2          b2
```

Each menu has some generic and specific features For their products.

Like color, weight, dimensions for all menus

Or screens_type and resolution only for TVs

Or processor and graphic only for the computers

Also, based on these features, I have a filter system (search) for each menu to finds products.

Now

When I create a new product, I want to import the features associated with that menu.

Now my problem is, I do not know how to implement the database for the feature table So that it can be searched and comparable.

This is my solution:

## scenario:

create a feature table:

## table: feature

```
id     |   menu_id   |    name    
1             1           color
2             2           color
3             1           screen
4             2           graphic
```

I create a new product. I select the menu for it and  I save the product.

In the second step, I will open the product again so Features are loaded according to the selected menu.

Then I enter the features and save the product again.

Now I save the features data as a json field in the product table.

But I think It should be a better solution.

## Can you help me do this?

Comment: JSON data represents unnormalized data.  Instead, you could store each feature in a separate row.

Comment: Just make use of 'SELECT' and 'UPDATE' queries in PHP, you could aswell use AJAX to gain data asynchronously. If you couldn't manage to solve it out I'll try to help you later on once I get home :-)